# Inserting selected value from populated mysql dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql, atom-editor

I am trying to insert the selected value from a drop down that was populated from a reference table in my database. I followed a tutorial for a dynamic dropdown but now I would like to take the value and insert it. The problem is it keeps taking the echo the tutorial uses. Is there a way I can make that selected value a new variable? It currently inserts "< php echo $team_name"

```
<div>
    <label>Home Team</label>
    <select name="home_team" style="width:125px;>
        <option value="">Select Team</option>
        <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM team";
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM team_name");
            // loop
            foreach ($results as $team_name) {
        ?>
        <option value="<php echo $team_name["cid"]; ?><?php echo $team_name["team_name"]; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
   </select>
```

How I attempted to insert:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'register');
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "failed" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//var_dump($_POST);
$home_team = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['home_team']);
$home_team = $home_team;
$query = "INSERT INTO game_table (home_team)
          VALUES('$home_team')";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
//echo $query;
//echo $home_team;
//header('location: index.php');
```

Comment: try to echo $home_team value and verify that value, I think you need to remove single quotes, also try to insert hard code value.

Comment: @NitinDhomse where can i echo the $home_team, It does end up inserting "echo $team_name["team_name"]" into the table when I push to insert but anytime I try to adjust that line of code it effects what is populated for the drop down.

Comment: Just echo before inserting into database to verify you are getting the value or not

Comment: Can you also include the list of columns of your tables?

Comment: @HazeErasmo sure I will add them above, the columns of this table are home_team, away_team, datetime

Comment: @NitinDhomse it does not echo anything when I attempt so I am unsure now what the problem is. Not sure why.

Comment: I'll try to replicate your code.

Comment: @HazeErasmo if I echo my $query, before I submit it echos " INSERT INTO game_table (home_team) VALUES('') and the same when I echo again after I submit so I do not think a variable is reaching there.

Comment: How you will get the value of the select by $home_team = $home_team; use jquery or javascript to get the value and assign to variable.

Comment: @HazeErasmo I used the suggested edit below by nazish and now my insert into mysql is <php echo $row['cid']; ?> so it is recognizing that as home_team

Comment: can you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

please follow this.

```
<select name="home_team" style="width:125px;>
    <option value="">Select Team</option>
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM team";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<php echo $row['cid']; ?>"><?php echo $row["team_name"]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

may be this should work

Comment: I used your changes and now it inserts <php echo $row['cid']; ?> into mysql so did not fix it but that is progress

Answer (score 0):

Try this. There was a couple of missing `"` and `?` in your code.

```
<select name="home_team" style="width:125px;">
  <option value="">Select Team</option>
  <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM team";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    foreach ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row["cid"]; ?>">
          <?php echo $row["team_name"]; ?>
      </option>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Okay I used this and now it does not insert anything, should I be trying the same insert code using home_team?

Comment: no data was sent, does not echo anything at the moment.

Comment: And if this still doesn't work. Check `cid` column value.

Comment: This edit gave me a blank page when I tried to refresh